# Login to Jenkins via URL

Tags: java, jenkins

I want to download a file (slave-agent.jnlp) from Jenkins Server which User ans password are required. (using Java)

Since it is not possible to give user and password in the URL, What is the way that it can be achieved?

Thanks,
Doron

Comment: Try using the "jnlpCredentials" parameter. For more info read the following: https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-16273

Comment: @Mark I am not sure if i got it right, jnlpCredentials is something that is defined in the jenkins-slave.xml file. this file is not the yet sine my slave is not created yet. what i am trying to do is to connect the master jenkins server and after the login is done, download the salve-agent.jnlp file

Comment: Create the slave on the server first and this will give you a JNLP URL that you can use to launch the slave. See my shell script below

Comment: @Mark, thanks for the suggestion but in my specific case I can not create / initialise the slave before. As my target is to download the slave-agent.jnlp do yo know away to find this file on the jenkins master server? where if is located...?

Comment: The URL for the jnlp file is associated with the slave you setup on the server. Create one and Jenkins will provide a link. It's done this way so that the slave can be centrally configured, even though it's running remotely (To labor the point, each configured slave will have its own JNLP URL). If you want to avoid server-side configuration altogether, I suggest looking at the Swarm plugin (Link in my answer below)

Answer (score 2):

This is the shell script I use to launch my slave node:

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ ! -e slave.jar ] || [ ! -e commons-codec-1.7.jar ]; then
   curl -O "https://my.jenkins.host/jnlpJars/slave.jar"
   curl -O "https://my.nexus.repo/service/local/repositories/central/content/commons-codec/commons-codec/1.7/commons-codec-1.7.jar"
fi

nohup java -jar slave.jar -cp commons-codec-1.7.jar \
     -jnlpUrl https://my.jenkins.host/computer/My_slave/slave-agent.jnlp \
     -jnlpCredentials myuser:myusertoken \
     > $0.log 2>&1 &
```

Notes:

- My slaves are spun up on an adhoc basis so I choose register a slave called "My_slave" and then using the slave's JNLP URL to run the slave on the other machine. This means the slave is still configured centrally
- Adding the commons-codec jar may not be necessary anymore. This was a work-around to a authentication bug [JENKINS-9679](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-9679)
- I have configured a user token in my Jenkins user account. This avoids my having to put my password in the shell script

Other notes:

- Using the SSH plugin is the simplest way to configure slaves, provided the slave nodes are unix and you have the SSH keys setup properly. This JNLP approach works but is fiddly.
- Another interesting plugin to consider is the [swarm plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Swarm+Plugin). I haven't used it but I like the way a slave does not have to be pre-registered.

### Update

Nice concise blog posting on how to use the swarm plugin:

- http://www.donaldsimpson.co.uk/?p=500

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to mention username and password in the url as follows:

```
http://username:password@example.com/
```

Comment: When I do it the login fails and the URL is changed to http://host:8080/jenkins/login?from=%2Fjenkins